# How to detect if a script is executed directly from the node console

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console

Is it possible to determine whether the current script is executed from **using the node.js console**:

```
$ node
> require('./script');
```

or from running *the classic way* of **using a file** like:

```
node script.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check `module.parent !== null`. If that is true, then the file is being `require()`d from some other script. If that statement is false, then it is the script loaded initially from the command line.

If you want to know specifically if the parent was the repl, you could check `module.parent && module.parent.id === 'repl'`.

`module.parent` is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent).